# Automatic Update of child property in a EditFormTemplate

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-ajax

#### Context:

With a RadGrid, you can have [build-in automatic CRUD operation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/automatic-datasource-operations). But those operation seems to be possible only on the source/father table.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="myLinqDataSource" runat="server"
                    ContextTypeName="ExempleDataContext" TableName="Order"/>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="myRadGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="myLinqDataSource">
    <MasterTableView .../>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

While will be able to display property of Parent or Child:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CustomerId" HeaderText="CustomerId"
                         SortExpression="CustomerId" UniqueName="CustomerId"/>                             
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Product.Name" HeaderText="Product.Name"
                         SortExpression="Product.Name" UniqueName="Product.Name" />
```

And bind them in your EditForm:

```
Customer Id :
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_CustomerId" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Bind("CustomerId")%>' AutoPostBack="false" />

Product Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Product_Name" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Bind("Product.Name")%>' AutoPostBack="false" />
```

But only the "Father field" (here `CustomerId`)  get update.
When `Product.Name` is ignored and do not throw any error.

#### Exemple Dbml Schema:

[image: DbmlExemple]

#### What I tryed:

- Adding  Child Primary key to the Grid `DataKeyNames`.
- Adding `RetrieveDataTypeFromFirstItem="true"`, to `MasterTableView` trying to force him to get the type off the sub Item.
- And classical telerik vodoo, ending using manual insert and ItemCommand event.

#### Nb:

- Inplace and automated Update works. Only the Templated Form failed to bind.

Comment: I reduce the code to the bare minimum as a telerik Mcve could be quite long and messy. If the is any missing information i will gladly edit them into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AJAX (working on C# version of telerik), but AFAIK, you can't use such syntax as "Product.Name". Bindings refers only to fields inside class, in your case it is something like

```
class Product()
{
   public int Id
   public string Name
}  

class Customer()
{
   public int Id
   public string Name
}   

class Order()
{
   public int Id
   public int CustomerId
   public int ProductId
}
```

Which means, you can refer only directly to class properties. If you populate your container with data type of i.e. Customer, you can only make binding to Id and Name property.

To achieve what you want to do, you can create custom DTO class, for example

```
  class FullDataObject()
  {
          public int ProductId
          public string ProductName
          public int CustomerId
          public string CustomerName
          public int OrderId
  }
```

Then create collection of those objects and populate it with data from DB, and manipulate the data from your container.

If you want to stick to Build in CRUD option, you need to decide what type of object you want to edit inside of your container - Either Order, Customer or Product.

Since you have quite simple relations betweens your tables, which are one-to-zero-or-one, I'd go with creating DTO class, to easy manage data.

Best luck

Comment: "_you can't use such syntax as "Product.Name"_" Well bind display the right data, only the update fail. The Dbml is a dummy one taken from Google Image and code as been edit according to it, so it's not a proof of complexity. But you are still right on this point.

Comment: In fact the real issue could be in the `LinqDataSource`  using some kind of anonimous type.

Comment: And Ajax refers to Asp.net Ajax so it can be C# or Vb but not really related.

Comment: And an other point no the class you present is not how Dbml made them it will be more `private EntityRef<Customer> _Customer;` with `public Customer Customer
  {
   get
   {
    return this._Customer.Entity;
   }
   set
   {`

Comment: And last point, every build in option work on no matter how nested you want them if you don't use "TemplateEditForm", every inplace or automatic form would work out of the box.

Comment: I'm not pendantric or picky, you spend time writting an answer. The least I can do is to spend some time reviewing it. I will try to adress the main point latter : the idea of DTO and linQDataSource.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to show you an example how operate on DB objects on code behind. For me, Binding Product.Name doesn't work at all (WPF and C#). Anyway, main idea of my answer is to put as much as you can to code behind and as few as you can to your xaml code.